# Making a formula for 2 columns

Tags: excel-formula

I need to make a formula in excel where if column 1 is less than 1.99 and and column 2 is 1, it should return a true. How do I do this?

I am not excel savy, still learning.

Comment: `=AND(A1<1.99,B1=1)`?????

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: =--(col 1 < 1)*(col 2 = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your column 1 is A and column 2 is B, then you can use the following formula:

```
=--((A1 < 1.99) * (B1 = 1))
```

Here, each bracket will return 1 if the condition is true, then it will be multiplied (*) so that it will return 1 only if both conditions are met.

Then we have -- sign in the beginning to ensure it will return number instead of string (taking negative sign two times so it wont change the value)